# React-Redux-Firebase -- find documents by list of ids

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux-firebase

In my firebase database I have structure like this:

```
customers
 -- customer1
    customerId: 
        "customer1"
    timestamp: 
        1566294149128
    isActive: 
        true
 -- customer2
    customerId: 
        "customer2"
    timestamp: 
        1566294149128
    isActive: 
        true
 -- customer3
    customerId: 
        "customer3"
    timestamp: 
        1566294149128
    isActive: 
        true
```

I know that I want to fetch only customers with `customerId IN [customer1, customer3]`. And I don't know how to achieve it either in plain js or by using react-redux-firebase.
I tried to connect my react component using:

```
 firebaseConnect((props) => {
        const queryParams = [`orderByChild=customerId`, `equalTo=customer1`,`equalTo=customer3`];
        return [
            {
                path: "customers",
                storeAs: "searchableCustomers",
                queryParams,
            },
        ]
    }),
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it
a) Using react-redux-firebase
b) Using plain js without react

Edit: Adding screenshot of my real database. The `threads` path equals `customers` path in my post

[image: screen of real database]

Comment: Please replace the schematic data structure with the actual screenshot of your database.

Comment: done. But in my actual database the path customers have different name threads but it's the same and I want for example get data from threads with ids `016fa` and `0044a`

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with react-redux-firebase myself, but does it support `customerId IN [customer1, customer3]`? Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support `IN` queries natively, so the library would have to have built that on top of the native API.

Comment: Unfortunately the library doesn't support `IN`  but maybe you could give me a little tip on how to  implement `IN` using plain firebase js client ?

Comment: On the JavaScript SDK you'll have to perform a separate query for each value, and merge them together client-side.